# Собрать видео из изображений средствами opencv

Tags: python, opencv, видео

Могу ли я средствами opencv собрать видео из отдельных кадров?
Если да, то как это сделать?

Comment: похожий вопрос [How to write a video file with OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4872383/4279)

Answer (score 1):

[Аналогичный вопрос в англоязычной версии SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43048725/python-creating-video-from-images-using-opencv)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
try:
    from pathlib import Path
except ImportError:             # Python 2
    from pathlib2 import Path

p = Path('/path/to/dir_with_images')

#читаем кадры
imgs = [cv2.imread(str(f)) for f in p.glob('*.jpg')]

# создаем видео
height, width, layers = imgs[0].shape
video = cv2.VideoWriter(r'd:/temp/video.avi',-1,1,(width,height))
_ = [video.write(i) for i in imgs]

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
video.release()
```

Comment: 1- `-1` параметр не работает на моей Ubuntu машине. Вы на Windows запускали? 2- порядок у `glob('*.jpg')` не определён (порядок кадров вероятно имеет значение) 3-  list comprehension вместо обычного цикла тут странно выглядит. 4- `destroyAllWindows()` вызов обычно последним идёт

Comment: @jfs, да на Windows... по пути `r'd:/temp/video.avi'` - это сразу заметно...

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы создать [MJPEG](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MJPEG) видео из jpg кадров, указанных в командной строке с помощью OpenCV:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Usage: create-video <images>..."""
import sys
import cv2  # $ pip install opencv-python

frames = sys.argv[1:]          # paths to images in order
frame = cv2.imread(frames[0])  # get size from the 1st frame
writer = cv2.VideoWriter(
    'output.avi',
    cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG'),   # codec
    25.0,  # fps
    (frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]),  # width, height
    isColor=len(frame.shape) > 2)
for frame in map(cv2.imread, frames):
    writer.write(frame)
writer.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Пример:

```
$ create-video frame{001..250}.jpg
```

См. в документации OpenCV: [Saving a Video](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html).

Для теста, jpg-кадры можно получить из видео, используя ffmpeg команду:

```
$ ffmpeg -i $(youtube-dl --get-url 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PpTqzVGPLQY' | grep http | head -1) -t 10 'frame%03d.jpg'
```

[image: frames]

Интерфейс у `VideoWriter()` относительно простой, поэтому для создания сжатого видео с помощью кодека со множеством настроек подойдут более специализированные инструменты такие как ffmpeg.

Comment: симпатичное "кино" получилось :)